# jQuery Percentage Loader - "Controllable" example

Tags: jquery

I want to use the jQuery Percentage Loader.

in their site I don't find a easy working demo to download and use.

I need help on finding an easy demo code of their "Controllable" example.

jQuery Percentage Loader site:
https://bitbucket.org/Better2Web/jquery.percentageloader

jQuery Percentage Loader demo site:
http://widgets.better2web.com/loader/

Comment: Right click on the demo site > View Source.

Comment: thanks,but no easier way? :)

Answer (score 0):

Do a view page source from your browser,it will clear you lot of things like

1.What are the scripts/css to include
2.Html tags and the usage pattern

The example is using

```
 <div id="controllable-loader"></div>
```

and

including this in the header section.

```
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.gif" type="image/gif" />
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

<script src="scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="loader/jquery.percentageloader-01a.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a simple solution that I used, which works.

1. Just cut n paste their demo.html page code from the jquery percentage loader plugin into a jsp file.
2. Reference their library and jquery in the head portion of your page.
3. You can put the jsp in the Web Content directory of a java dynamic web application, so no servlet is needed because the jsp is a compiled servlet.
4. Add Tomcat to the project and use: host/web context name/jsp name.

The demo.html file is located in the jquery.percentageloader folder.

Answer (score 0):

I created a loader generator for this plugin. That generator enables you to easily define colors for a controllable loader and then gives you the code you need to implement it. You can access it here: http://nadavr.com/projects/percentage-loader-color-generator/